# How to run Auto Hot Key script only when WebStorm and Visual Studio is on?

Tags: typescript, autohotkey

I work with TS a lot lately. I love the ` sign that allows me to do the string interpolation. However, I forget to use it, so I created AHK script that switches the backtick and ' for me:

```
'::`
`::'
~::~
"::"
```

works fine, but now it works everywhere, even here. I would like this script to work only in WebStorm and Visual Studio. Googled, found `IfWinActive`, but it expects the full window title. In my case, the window title changes a lot, because it also contains the project title, path to .ts file, for example, the title could be

> "My Cool Project [C:\path\to\file.ts] - WebStorm"

hence `IfWinActive` will not work. What I need is a command like

`ifWinTitleContains "WebStorm" or ifWinTitleContains "Visual Studio"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ahk_exe instead of the title to identify the window ([ahk_exe](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe)).

For Visual Studio:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe devenv.exe
'::`
`::'
~::~
"::" 
#IfWinActive ;End of WinActive scope
```

You can get the name of the exe from the Windows Spy (Right-click on the AHK icon).

Comment: I'd create a group of the two ahk_exe's in the autoexecute section and use `#IfWinActive, ahk_group ThisGroup` to make the remapping context-sensitive.